# Number of mass nouns when used with mutually exclusive coordinate adjectives

Tags: grammar, american-english

My question concerns the number attached to mass nouns when modified by multiple adjectives meant to imply different versions of a common type. An illustrative case follows:

> Belgian and Swiss chocolate **differ** from American chocolate.

vs.

> Belgian and Swiss chocolate **differs** from American chocolate.

The first version is far clearer than the second version, since it is most natural to interpret the subject as elliptically referring to the compound "Belgian chocolate and Swiss chocolate" rather than to any chocolate that is Belgian and Swiss at the same time. But the second version accords more with the rote assignment of singular number to mass nouns in American English.

Can anyone recommend an authority that settles this question? I mainly refer to The Chicago Manual of Style as often as possible for the writing I edit, but of course it is only a starting point.

Comment: Out of curiosity -- have you encountered someone who actually believes that it should be "differs"? (I ask because that isn't a mistake I ever remember encountering.)

Comment: Chocolate of both Belgian and Swiss origins is of one kind, and that **differs** from American chocolate. Also @ruakh

Comment: @Kris: The question specifies that we're talking about "multiple adjectives meant to imply different versions" -- what *CGEL* calls the "discrete sets" interpretation. (It's a general principle that when discussing the grammar of a sentence, we're actually discussing its grammar *under a given interpretation*.)

Comment: Yes; I'd say we've got an unholy conflict of rules here.  There is one Google hit for "Both Belgian and Swiss chocolate is" and zero for "Both Belgian and Swiss chocolate are". Unuseful. There aren't that many if we drop the 'both' (which allows false positives in), but both forms of agreement are used. I'd probably use 'hot and cold water is available', but 'the hot and cold water are provided separately' myself. Second-order notionality.

Comment: Frankly, I read the sentence, without noticing anything odd, and understood what it meant right away. On revisiting it after the question, I could parse it with no difficulty. Where's an issue?

Answer (score -3):

You need to have subject-verb agreement, so you use *differ* after a plural noun and *differs* after a singular noun.

How to interpret this is nuanced, but, simplistically, both of these are correct:

> ✔ Belgian and Swiss ***chocolates*** <sup>[plural]</sup> **differ** from American chocolates.
>
> ✔ Belgian and Swiss ***chocolate*** <sup>[singular]</sup> **differs** from American chocolate.

Also simplistically, both of these are incorrect:

> ✘ Belgian and Swiss ***chocolates*** <sup>[plural]</sup> **differs** from American chocolates.
>
> ✘ Belgian and Swiss ***chocolate*** <sup>[singular]</sup> **differ** from American chocolate.

However, it's sometime's not as simplistic as that. (I provide another analysis at the end of this answer.)

---

Understanding this, all that remains is how you parse the noun—if you're actually referring to a plural (countable) entity or a singular (mass) entity. But however you interpret that, the verb needs to match the noun count.

---

I had a comment suggest that this is wrong because the following is used:

> The hot and cold water are provided separately.

But that still matches what I'm saying. In that sentence there are two things (hot water and cold water) and they ***are*** provided separately. The most important thing is matching the number of things with the correct verb form.

Whether you decide to put an *s* on the end of a combined plural noun (*the hot and cold water* or *the hot and cold waters*) is simply stylistic; it's immaterial to the form the verb should take.

---

In some cases, the syntax alone is insufficient to determine singularity or plurality. It depends on how you parse the sentence.

For instance, both of these are possible, depending on context and interpretation:

> ✔ 1.The choir *was* singing.
> [Commonly US English, where *choir* is treated as a singular noun.]
>
> ✔ 2. The choir *were* singing.
> [Commonly UK English, where the *choir* is treated as a plural noun.]

Or:

> ✔ 1. My fish and chips *was* delicious.
> [I ate the single food item of *fish and chips* from the menu.]
>
> ✔ 2. My fish and chips *were* delicious.
> [I ordered two food items: an order of salmon and a side of chips.]

In all interpretations of the noun, if you consider the noun to be singular, then it takes a singular verb; if you consider the noun to be plural, then it takes a plural verb.

---

Revisiting the start of this answer, *if* you style the spelling of the noun differently, such that *Belgian and Swiss* ***chocolate*** is considered a plural, then the following would be correct:

> ✔ Belgian and Swiss ***chocolate*** <sup>[plural]</sup> **differ** from American chocolate.

The spelling of this sentence exactly matches the earlier spelling in which I said the sentence was incorrect. However, it's incorrect when the noun is considered a *singular* concept, but correct when it's considered a *plural* concept.

Comment: But there are internet examples of say 'the hot and cold water are provided separately', where notional agreement seems more natural than proximity agreement. ELU prefers that claims be substantiated with linked and attributed references; unsupported claims often come across as (and sometimes are) mere hopeful opinion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Which exactly matches subject-verb agreement. (1) *The hot water **is** provided separately.* (2) *The hot and cold water(s) **are** provided separately.* It's the subjects and the verb that are most important, not that an *s* has been put at the end of the noun.

Comment: A bald "You need to have subject-verb agreement, so you use 'differ' after a plural noun and 'differs' after a singular noun' [I assume you mean noun-form; arguably 'people' is a plural noun manifesting as a singular noun-form, with the occasional plural noun-form (and 'peoples'] "  is too simplistic. "Fish and chips is my favourite takeaway." "Bacon and eggs was on the menu." Plural noun-form next to the verb, but singular (notionally informed) verb-form, ie singular agreement. The issue is complex.

Comment: Grammatically, 'Belgian and Swiss chocolate' may well be considered as a deleted form of 'Belgian chocolate and Swiss chocolate', which original would certainly take 'differ'; the rules governing agreement with such deleted forms are not set in stone, are rarely if ever met in even lengthier grammars, and need supporting references if they are cited.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Again, you are quite correct—but not contradicting me. In *fish and chips*, it is considered a *single* noun, so it takes a singular verb. *My fish and chips **was** delicious*. But if you are actually parsing it as two distinct items (a piece of salmon as well as a side-order of chips) then it would be *my fish and chips **were** delicious*. The verb follows how you *parse* the plurality or singularly, not what the actual words are—although they are commonly the same.

Comment: Are you **sure** that you can categorically say that the following is incorrect: *Belgian and Swiss **chocolate** **differ** from American chocolate*? Like Edwin Ashworth, I think there is a natural reading of that sentence that renders it acceptable. Here is a related example from COCA: *Semisweet and bittersweet **chocolate are** similar and can usually be interchanged in recipes.* There are lots of examples of this particular construction in google books (just search for "semisweet and bittersweet chocolate are").

Comment: @linguisticturn I have updated my answer one more time to make it clear that I do not think your example is explicitly incorrect. It depends *entirely* on how you parse the singularity or plurality, and how you style the spelling of the noun.

Comment: Better, but it would be *even* better if, instead of providing extra-linguistic markers [singular] and [plural], you placed the relevant sentences in contexts that force the singular or plural reading. Otherwise one might object that there is simply no context in which *Belgian and Swiss chocolate differ from American chocolate* is definitely unacceptable. And in fact, I have trouble imagining such a context in a world in which there is Belgian chocolate and there is Swiss chocolate, but no **one** kind of chocolate called 'Belgian and Swiss chocolate'.

Comment: @linguisticturn But language doesn't always work that way. Exactly the same words can have two different meanings, as is the case here. Not only *could* Belgian and Swiss chocolate be referring to some of one kind and some of another (which I think is likely), but there's no practical reason why somebody couldn't mix the two together into a single piece—and call it Belgian and Swiss. The meaning could be forced from the syntax (and I started with what I think is more common), but some things are simply ambiguous. Here, the intention informs the verb form.

Comment: Yes, but it's better to 'show' rather than 'tell': give context that makes the intention obvious. Also, examples should be taken in their most likely meaning. You now agree that *Belgian and Swiss chocolate* likely refers to 'some of one kind and some of another'. But then it is *differ* (not *differs*) that is by default correct. It is only incorrect if *Belgian and Swiss chocolate*  has the less likely meaning (a single kind of chocolate). An answer should reflect that and mention the more likely meaning first, and the less likely as an afterthought. Your answer has it the other way around.

Comment: @linguisticturn I didn't say that was the most likely at all—look at my answer again. I only mentioned that in my previous comment as a *possibility*. The most likely scenario is exactly what I said at the start of my answer—that they are two different (plural) types of chocolate; thereby, making it that *Belgian and Swiss chocolates differ*. Also, I didn't say in my previous comment *some of one kind and some of another*. I specifically said a single *piece* that is a mixture of different kinds, thereby causing a hybrid or combination.